# Is "ON UPDATE" specific for TIMESTAMP cols?

Tags: mysql

Is `ON UPDATE` specific for `TIMESTAMP` cols?

When I use it on cols with other types it causes a syntax error.

Comment: you mean like `someintfield on update set 42` kind of thing?

Comment: You can use [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html) to do anything you want on any column ON UPDATE.

Comment: @MarcB Yes, but this syntax cause error.

Comment: at the docs that Bridge linked to below, on update is for timestamps only. if you want to update other field types, use a trigger.

Answer (score 2):

Whilst I'm no Mysql expert, yes it looks like that particular syntax is TIMESTAMP specific.

From the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html):

> To specify automatic properties, use the DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and
>   ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP clauses.

Then a little later:

> Use of DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is
>   specific to TIMESTAMP.

Comment: Maybe it means when you use CURRENT_TIMESTAMP with the cluase, because definitely DEFAULT is not specifc to TIMESTAMP cols!

Comment: @csstd yes you're right, but you haven't told us what you're trying to do or the error message you're encountering.

Comment: OK, I think I should use triggers. But i expected a solid answer in the MYSQL docs.